# In React-admin transform method, Why it is unavailable to get current state?

Tags: react-admin

Hi Im using  `"react": "^16.13.1"` and `"react-admin": "^3.8.1"`

Im working on page using

```js
const transform = (data) => {
    if (option === 'status') {
      return {
        comment: data.comment,
        ids: udiEditDisplayInfo.selectedIds,
        status: data.statusToBe,
      };
    } else if (option === 'customer') {
      console.error('Transform option is Customer!!');
      //To be implemented
    }
  };
 return (
<Edit {...props} actions={<TopToolbar />} transform={transform} onSuccesss={onSuccess} onFailure={onFailure}>
      <SimpleForm toolbar={<CustomToolbar />} redirect={false}>
...
 <RadioGroup  name="option" value={option} onChange={handleChange}>
            <FormControlLabel value="customer" control={<Radio />} label="Customer" />
    ...
)
```

when Radio button clicked, 'option' state changed.

the problem is .. in transform method, they can not recognize the change of option state!
options is still default value(customer)

somebody help me please..

Comment: Try to set the `source` of the RadioGroup like
`<RadioGroup name="option" value={option} onChange={handleChange} source="option">`